# Why might json_encode fail to encode a PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, slim

I've been working with Slim Framework 2 and it's fantastic. However,  I have a problem regarding the limit of JSON. I have a SQL query, that will help me get 3 elements. Title, description and urgency.

Whenever I put Description, and I want to see the result of the JSON, it displays nothing. However, if I remove description it appears but is a mile long. So my question is, what's the limit of JSON and can it be larger?

Here's a code sample:

```
 $app->get('/api/notes/project/{project}/{user_id}', function(Request $request, Response $response)
            {


                $id = $request->getAttribute('user_id');
                $project = $request->getAttribute('project_id');
                $sql = "SELECT notes.title, notes.description, notes.urgency from NOTES WHERE notes.responsible = $id AND notes.project_id = '1'";

                try{


                    //GET DB OBJECT
                    $db = new db();
                    //connect
                    $db = $db->connect();

                    //FETCH OBJECT
                    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
                    $user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $db = null;
                    echo json_encode($user);

                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
                }

            });
```

Comment: This query looks like `$id` could inject SQL into it - please swap to parameter binding. PDO does support that, and the code is (likely) not safe to go live with at the moment.

Comment: My guess is that `$user` is populated fine, but `json_encode` is failing because your data is not in UTF-8. Comment out the `echo` statement and try `print_r($user)` instead and let me know if you get data or not.

Comment: There's normally no need to guess. Just ask [json_last_error()](http://php.net/json_last_error).

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked well. Appreciate the time that you took to answer that. Didn't know about the echo issue.

Comment: @halfer Yes. I will change the $id, it was more of a test. Thank you.